# Computing the pull-back of a simple one-form

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms, pullback

Let $(u, v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the 1-form $\alpha_{(u,v)} : \mathrm{T}_{(u, v)}\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{align}
\alpha_{(u,v)}(w) &= (e^v ~\mathrm{d}u + u ~\mathrm{d}v) \cdot w \\
&= e^v \cdot w_1 + u \cdot w_2 \\
w &= w_1 \frac{\partial }{\partial u} + w_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial v}
\end{align}
Consider additionally the function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\phi(x, y, z) = (x+z, xy)$. I wish to compute the pullback of $\alpha$ by $\phi$.

---

Here is my attempt. I am wondering if I have done this correctly. The pullback is defined by,
\begin{align}
\phi^*\alpha(r) = \alpha_{\phi(x, y,z)}(\mathrm{T}_{(x, y,z)} \phi \cdot r)
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{T}_{(x, y,z)} \phi: \mathrm{T}_{(x, y,z)}\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathrm{T}_{\phi(x, y,z)}\mathbb{R}^2$ is the derivative map and $r\in \mathrm{T}_{(x,y,z)}\mathbb{R}^3$. I compute the Jacobian of $\phi$ as
\begin{align}
\mathrm{T}_{(x, y,z)}\phi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ y & x & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Writing $r = r_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + r_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial y} + r_3 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ I compute,
\begin{align}
\phi^*\alpha(r) &= \alpha_{(x+z, xy)}((r_1 + r_3)~\mathrm{d}u + (yr_1 + x r_2) ~\mathrm{d}v) \\
&= e^{xy} (r_1 + r_3) + (x+z) (y r_1 + xr_2).
\end{align}
Have I done this correctly? Anything that could be improved?

---

A commenter suggested to write this in the form $\phi^*\alpha = a ~\mathrm{d}x + b ~\mathrm{d}y + c~\mathrm{d}z$. By identification, we have,
\begin{align}
\phi^*\alpha = (e^{xy} + y(x+z)) ~\mathrm{d}x +x (x+z) ~\mathrm{d}y + e^{xy} ~\mathrm{d}z.
\end{align}

Comment: So $\alpha = e^v\,du + u\,dv$. When most of us ask for $\phi^*\alpha$, we want a $1$-form on $\Bbb R^3$, i.e., something of the form $f\,dx + g\,dy + h\,dz$.

Comment: Yes, your computation is correct. However, to figure out pullbacks, you only have to [learn a few rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4395355/568204). So, while what you did is certainly correct (namely, plugging in arbitary vectors and evaluating the value of the forms on the vectors using the definitions alone), this is inefficient (we rarely compute things from definitions alone; we use theorems to help us along). So, I suggest taking a look at my linked answer where I list a few properties and provide example calculations.