# How to compute the pullback of $f(x,y,z) = (xy, xz, yz)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

> Let $f(x,y,z) := (xy, xz, yz)$. Compute the pullback $f^*\omega$, where $\omega$ runs through all wedge products of basis forms $dx$, $dy$, $dz$.

The definition of pullback that I know is:

> The definition for the pullback of a $\mathcal{C}^{r+1}$ mapping $g: U \rightarrow V$ and a $\mathcal{C}^r$-smooth differential $p$-form $\omega$ in $V$ is
>
> $$ (g^*\omega)_x(v_1,\ldots,v_p) = \omega_{g(x)}(Dg_x(v_1),\ldots,Dg_x(v_p))$$

First of all, I am not quite sure if I understand the statement of the problem correctly as the part

> "where $\omega$ runs through all wedge products"

is a bit ambiguous to me. Does this mean that $\omega = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$? If yes, then I think since $\omega$ is a $3$-form and the Jacobi-matrix is given by

$$(Df)_{(x,y,z)} =\begin{bmatrix}y &x &0\\ z &0 &x\\ 0 &z &y \end{bmatrix}$$

we have for $v_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ and

$$a_i := D_f(v_i)  =\begin{bmatrix} x_i+y_i \\x_i+z_i \\ y_i+z_i  \end{bmatrix}$$

by definition of the pullback that

$$(f^*\omega)(v_1,v_2,v_3) = ((d_x \wedge d_y \wedge d_z))(v_1,v_2,v_3) = \det(D_f(v_1),D_f(v_2),D_f(v_3)). $$

, where the last equation follows from the fact that the wedge product of the canonical basis forms is the determinant.

Could you please tell me if this is correct so far?

EDIT: Using Masacroso's and peek-a-boo's suggestions I came up with the following:

$$f^*(dx) = d(f^*x) = d(x \circ f) = d(xy) = ydx + xdy$$
$$f^*(dy) = d(f^*y) = d(y \circ f) = d(xz) = zdx + xdz$$
$$f^*(dz) = d(f^*z) = d(z \circ f) = d(yz) = zdy + ydz$$

\begin{align}
f^*(dx \wedge dy) &= f^*(dx) \wedge f^*(dy) = (ydx + xdy) \wedge (zdx + xdz) \\ 
&= ydx \wedge zdx + ydx \wedge xdz + xdy \wedge zdx + xdy \wedge xdz
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f^*(dx \wedge dz) &= f^*(dx) \wedge f^*(dz) = (ydx + xdy) \wedge (zdy + ydz) \\ 
&= ydx \wedge zdy + ydx \wedge ydz + xdy \wedge zdy + xdy \wedge ydz
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f^*(dy \wedge dz) &= f^*(dy) \wedge f^*(dz) = (zdx + xdz) \wedge (zdy + ydz) \\
&= zdx \wedge zdy + zdx \wedge ydz + xdz \wedge zdy + xdz \wedge ydz
\end{align}

$$f^*(dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) = f^*(dz) \wedge f^*(dy) \wedge f^*(dz)$$

Is this correct or can we do more here?

Comment: They're asking you to compute $f^*({dx}),f^*(dy),f^*(dz),f^*(dx\wedge dy),f^*(dx\wedge dz),f^*(dy\wedge dz)$ and $f^*(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)$. At least that's how I read the question. Anyway, applying the definition is certainly one way to go, but it's not a good way in general to compute. All you need to know are a few basic rules: pullback commutes with wedge products, and exterior derivatives, and is linear, and you need to know how to calculate $df$ for a smooth function $f$; see [Calculating simple pullbacks](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4395355/568204) for examples.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I made an edit.

Comment: You can do more. Why did you stop? Continue simplifying the calculations for 2-forms and 3-form. Use what you previously calculated, and simplify the algebra (that's what they want you to do). Also, one comment (which you can ignore, since your first few calculations are fine) I have is that it is generally a good idea to use different letters for the coordinates on the domain and target. For example, $(x,y,z)$ on the target, and $(u,v,w)$ say on the domain, so $f^*(dx)=d(f^*x)=d(x\circ f)=d(uv)=u\,dv+v\,du$ (in this specific case, things are easy, so not as confusing, but it could be worse).

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thank you for your comment. However, I am having trouble with "simplifying the algebra". I can not see what to do more here than to "multiply out" the wedge products, but the resulting terms are just messy and I do not see how to simplify them further. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just multiply things out, and group them together. Don't worry if you don't get super simple coefficients. BUT, make sure you simplify completely using alternating nature of the wedge product. For example, you have some terms involving $(\text{stuff}) dx\wedge dx$. THis is automatically $0$. Likewise $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: use the fact that
$$
\begin{align*}
f^*\left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^n dx^k\right)&=\bigwedge_{k=1}^n f^*dx^k\\&=\bigwedge_{k=1}^n d(f^*x^k)\\&=\bigwedge_{k=1}^n d(x^k \circ f)\\&=\bigwedge_{k=1}^ndf^k\\
&=\bigwedge_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^m \partial_j f^k dx^j\right)
\end{align*}
$$
for $f:=(f^1,\ldots ,f^n)$. Example of solution for one case: using the above we have that
$$
\begin{align*}f^*(dx\wedge dy)&=(d(xy))\wedge d(xz))=(xdy+ydx)\wedge (xdz+zdx)\\
&=-xzdx\wedge dy+x^2dy\wedge dz-xydz\wedge dx \end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it should be $f := (f^1,\ldots,f^m)$ in the last line.

Comment: @3nondatur no, it is as I've written. The domain of $f$ have dimension $m$ here, and it image have dimension $n$